# Error when compiling Kivi using Buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, cython, buildozer

I am compiling the code in Python Kivy using the command "bulldozer android deploy".

```
Kivy version = 2.2.1
bulldozer version = 1.5.0
Python version = 3.0.2
```

Code:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivy.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        years = [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]

        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            # use_pagination= True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[("Год", dp(30))],
            row_data= [(str(year),) for year in years],
            sorted_on="Schedule",
            sorted_order="ASC",
            elevation=2)

        self.data_tables.bind(on_check_press=self.on_click_box)
        
        screen = MDScreen()
        screen.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        
        return screen

    def on_click_box(self, instance_table, current_row):
        print(current_row[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Example()
    app.run()
```

Please help in solving the problem. Text error:

> ```
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
>     # works only for write.
>     cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
>     rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
>     rwops.seek = NULL
>     rwops.read = NULL
>     rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
>                   ^
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:35:18: Cannot assign type 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1' to 'size_t
> (*)(SDL_RWops *, void *, size_t, size_t) noexcept'. Значения исключений несовместимы. Предлагаю добавить 'noexcept' к типу 'size_t
> ```
>
> (SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1'.
>
> ```
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
>     cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
>     rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
>     rwops.seek = NULL
>     rwops.read = NULL
>     rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
>     rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close
> ```

I found the file where the error is. Here is a code snippet where it occurs:

```
cdef SDL_RWops *rwops_bridge_to_bytesio(byteio):
    # works only for write.
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
    rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close
    return rwops
```

[image]

What have I done to solve the problem? added noexcept as described in the error:

```
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write noexcept
    rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close noexcept
```

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @toyota Supra, the error text is attached

Comment: @toyota Supra, I attached the program code, the error and the file where it occurs. Please help

Comment: I am not familiar  Kivy with bullzoer.

Comment: @toyota Supra, уrror in the C++ code

Comment: I used Python not c++.

Comment: The `noexcept` goes on the *function definition* of `rwops_bytesio_write`, not the point where you take the address. If it's a third-party library though, you're probably best using Cython 0.29.x to build it instead though

Comment: @DavidW, I solved my problem by installing a virtual environment and reinstalling the packages in it. After that everything compiles well.